# Get email from user logged in (Firebase security rules)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to be able to get the email of a user logged in using Firebase from the 'auth' variable and compare it with a value to a location in Firebase. If the email matches, then allow all data to be read across Firebase to the 'admin' user.

How can this be achieved as I've tried all sorts of combinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Firebase documentation on the `auth` variable in security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/rule/auth.html) says these properties are available:

> After a user is authenticated with one of the built-in providers, the auth variable will contain the following:
>
> **provider**  The authentication method used ("password", "anonymous", "facebook", "github", "google", or "twitter").
>
> **uid**   A unique user id, guaranteed to be unique across all providers.

There are no additional properties available, which is why most developers [store the user's information in their database as described in the documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing).

If you want to control the information that is available in the `auth` variable in security rules, you can also consider [minting your own tokens with Firebase custom authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this Frank, which is something I've already been doing in terms of storing auth data in data storage as well.It would be great if Firebase could provide a method to obtain the email in rules and then compare it in a location in the database for example, rather than minting tokens as you advise and that I've seen elsewhere